# What are good tips and suggestions for first-time Junta players?

Tags: teaching, junta

We'll be pulling Junta off the shelf for the first time in years, and our group will consist of players who haven't played since the last time years ago, and players who have never played it at all.

I've done a couple obvious things for setup - separated cards and chits into separate zipbags for ease of finding things. What other things can I do to help the game go smoothly?

edit: worth mentioning that we're expecting 8-10 people, so we plan to use the extra positions (Foreign Minister, Farm & Labor, Secretary of War).

Answer (score 4):

I guess the best thing you could do is to make sure there is at least one person really familiar with the rules, ideally someone who have played this game not so long ago. It's great to hear you are making effort to make the game more enjoyable for other players, I would like play a game with such game host. So, with your attitude I would say you're half way there.

As I said, I think the best thing you can do is to learn the rules really well, try going over them in your head (prepare yourself for explaining the rules). If possible, try to play the game yourself a few times before the event. I tried to find you a place to play Junta online, but all i got is **[PBEM version](http://www.junta-online.net/)**.

**[This](http://www.historygamer.com/2011/01/30/junta-how-to-play-this-fun-board-game/)** seems to me as a good rules refresher for Junta.

Comment: It's worth noting too that anyone familiar with the rules should not take advantage of other players' lack of knowledge of the rules. The game may be cutthroat, but it's no fun to anyone if they just lost a coup because they weren't told all the rules.

Answer (score 4):

First time playing, everyone has to use a cheesy spanish accent.

"Meester Prezidente, joo haz all deez monies! Geef me monies, hefe, and I protect joo!"